# Convert to scientific notation

Tags: c

How do I first convert numbers that I'm adding to scientific notation in C program . Then add them together, and once I have my final answer, then convert it back to scientific notation and return it?

Comment: Can you maybe give some more details about what you're trying to do? Some code might help too. Scientific notation is just a visual representation so I'm not sure why you need to convert anything. A number is a number, the only time scientific notation comes into it is when you display it.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a, b, c;
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b) != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected two floating point numbers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    c = a + b;
    printf("%13.6e + %13.6e = %13.6e\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
Enter two numbers: 13.456e34 +11.44225534e33
 1.345600e+35 +  1.144226e+34 =  1.460023e+35
```